# Trying to set state using useContext values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-state-management, react-state

Hi there I am creating a gatsby react app and my main goal on this page is to delete some localStorage and reset context AFTER render. The AFTER is important because i want my page to render with some data but after it has rendered, i want to delete that data. (I have some data in localStorage in order to have persistent state)

1. Is this even possible?
2. My first attempt looked like this :

   - For this code snippet, my component appears if i comment out the useEffect which makes sense but when I add the useEffect it doesn't render my component, which is expected but not what i want :(

```
const {data, setData} = useContext(context)

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('deleting');
  setData({});
  localStorage.removeItem('data');
}, []);


const components = [];
for (const item in data) {
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(data, item)) {
      const { dataItem } = data[item];
      components.push(<Component dataItem={dataItem} />);
    }
  }


return (
   <div>
     {components}
   <div>
);
```

3. My second attempt was a little similar the difference is I tried saving the data into a localState to see if that would allow it to persist even after it gets deleted and I am no longer grabbing the context in the child component, I'm instead grabbing it in the parent component and passing it as a prop to the child:

   - The problem here is that my localData is always an empty object. However my console statements show that data actually has data in it, but when i useState(data) my localData is always an empty object. Even if I useState({}) and then i setlocalData(data) i get an infinite loop :(

```
console.log(data);
const [localData, setlocalData] = useState(data); //this is the same data as in the other snippet
console.log(localCartInfo);

// rest of the code is the same except im now replacing data with localdata
```

If anybody who knows how react actually works can help me that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are you reading data in the context frm localStorage?

Comment: If yes you can use this hook to delete from localStorage
https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useFirstMountState.md
instead of useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by saving the context data into a cookie on first page load.
This worked better than setting a localState because it didnt require a component reload to set the cookie AND turns out a cookie works way better for my use case anyway due to the possibility of making it expire.

I did this like so :

```
let localData = {};

const {data, setData} = useContext(dataContext);

if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
      // create cookie with existing data before it gets deleted
      const cookieString = `localData=${JSON.stringify(data)}`;
      document.cookie = cookieString;
      localData = data;
    } else {
      // if data doesn't exist, get the data from the localData cookie
      localData = JSON.parse(document.cookie.substring(10));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to perform an action after render. Well, this is hacky but can be done using use simple trick, here's a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wood-wxmtq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I will try the setTimeout if i cant figure anything else out but i would like to avoid them if possible.

Comment: You should try to avoid such behaviors in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a local state and persist your data in it before deleting the data.

Then render that local state.

```
const {data, setData} = useContext(context);
const [value] = useState(data); // initialize on mount with the context value. No need to change that value later on

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('deleting');
  setData({});
  localStorage.removeItem('data');
}, []);


const components = [];
for (const item in value) { // here, read value instead of data
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(data, item)) {
      const { dataItem } = data[item];
      components.push(<Component dataItem={dataItem} />);
    }
  }


return (
   <div>
     {components}
   </div>
);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt seem to be working. value is always an empty object. But what's weird is my console logs print twice :
first iteration : 
- data = {}
- value = {}
; second iteration:
- data = {data}
-value = {} . So it looks like my state is getting the first value of data and not the 2nd one.